# Urban Airship receivedBackgroundNotification never called

Tags: iphone, push-notification, urbanairship.com

After reading all the guides, and after checking hundred of articles on the internet, I'm quite sure that the method receivedBackgroundNotification is never called.

Everything works perfect, but when the app is in background, a notification is shown and this method never is called. Seems to be impossible to get it working.

Assuming all the normal operations and the basic configuration is well done and is working, what can I do to intercept and manage background push notifications with this library?

I will appreciate a lot any help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following configured:

- Remote notifications background mode enabled in the target's capabilities
- Background app refreshed is enabled on your test device
- Assuming you are trying to use the UAPushNotificationDelegate, make sure you either have [automatic setup enabled](https://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/ios/#automatic-integration) or you are forwarding all the proper methods to UA SDK.

Apple will only wake up your application if you send the push notification with content-available=1 in the payload. The option is exposed in the composer as "background processing" or you can set it in the [iOS overrides](https://docs.urbanairship.com/api/ua/#schemas/iosoverrideobject) when using the push api.

Answer (score 0):

In Urban Airship iOS SDK v.13.4.0 if `func receivedBackgroundNotification(_ notificationContent: UANotificationContent, completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)` is not called you can handle notifications in `func receivedNotificationResponse(_ notificationResponse: UANotificationResponse, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)` if you display notifications as alerts. Remember that you should only handle the notifications with `actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier` (the user opened the app from the notification interface).

This is an example of `UAPushNotificationDelegate` implementation:

```
extension MyPushNotificationDelegate: UAPushNotificationDelegate {
    public func receivedForegroundNotification(_ notificationContent: UANotificationContent, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        completionHandler()
    }

    public func receivedBackgroundNotification(_ notificationContent: UANotificationContent, completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }

    public func receivedNotificationResponse(_ notificationResponse: UANotificationResponse, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        guard notificationResponse.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier else {
            completionHandler()
            return
        }
        someFunc() {
            completionHandler()
        }
    }

    public func extend(_ options: UNNotificationPresentationOptions = [], notification: UNNotification) -> UNNotificationPresentationOptions {
        [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    }
}
```