# How to capture background silent Push Notifications on UAPushNotificationDelegate for iOS?

Tags: ios, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I'm trying to implement **silent Push Notifications** on an iOS application and I have followed the Urban Airship [Getting Started](https://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/ios/#getting-started) for iOS but there's not a single sample application that portraits how to implement silent push notifications that can be captured on the **UAPushNotificationDelegate**. I have created a test application and it's working just fine. I'm currently getting simple Push Notifications.

I have been using their Push API endpoints through CURLs command and they work perfectly.

My goal is to understand a couple of things:

1. How to create a custom Urban Airship payload to contain a silent push notifications `({"aps":{"content-available" : 1}})`
2. How to create a custom action
3. How to implement the registration of a custom action
4. How to capture silent push notifications on the
   UAPushNotificationDelegate's `func receivedBackgroundNotification(_ notificationContent: UANotificationContent, completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Swift.Void)`

I would to be able to implement silent push notifications on my application and I would like to have the community help to do so. Here's a reference Apple documentation on the matter:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_updates_to_your_app_silently

And here are some questions from other UA customers with the same concern:
https://support.urbanairship.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115011296606-Differentiate-silent-notifications-from-normal-push-notification
https://support.urbanairship.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010098392-Custom-actions-while-app-in-background
https://support.urbanairship.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000003566-Background-notifications-working-on-some-devices-but-not-on-others

Answer (score 0):

1) Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50867062/1637562)

2) Custom action:

```
let customAction : UAAction = UAAction(block: {(args, completionHanlder) in
    // Do something with args

    completionHanlder(UAActionResult.empty())
})
```

3) Registering the action:

```
UAirship.shared().actionRegistry.register(customAction, name: "custom_action_name")
```

4) Implement the delegate and override the method. If you want your custom action to run, you need to define it in the payload as an `app_defined` action.